# How to get the word which is most repeated in a list of strings?

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings. I want to extract words  which has been repeated the most in the list.

For example :

```
List<string> mylist=new List<string>();
mylist.Add("book is good ");
mylist.Add("i like flowers ");
mylist.Add("i reading book");
```

I want extract **book** not **i**.

@user3185569 said in response the following code

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("book is good ");
mylist.Add("i like flowers ");
mylist.Add("i reading book");

var mostRepeatedWord = mylist.SelectMany(x => x.Split(new [] { " " }, 
                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                         .GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                         .Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this code extracted One word that contains words like the, in and etc.

I want to extract five meaningful words from my list. I tried to fix it, so I added a XML dictionary to my project that contains words like *the*, *in* and etc.
and fill list of this dictionary like this:

```
static List<string> notWord = new List<string>();
    public static void fillList()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"XMLDic.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            notWord.Add(node.InnerText); //or loop through its children as well
        }

    }
```

At first, I removed these words from my list and after that, in a five-stage loop, extract `mostRepeatedWord` and save it in a new list. The I remove `mostRepeatedWord` from the list and this process is repeated again for 5 more steps.

```
    public static List<string> finde(List<string> list)
    {
        List<string> newlist = new List<string>();

        fillList();
        delStr(list, "", true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            var mostRepeatedWord = list.SelectMany(x => x.Split(new[] { " " },
                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                         .GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                         .Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();

            if (mostRepeatedWord!="")
                newlist.Add(mostRepeatedWord);
            delStr(list, mostRepeatedWord, false);
        }
        return newlist;
    }
```

Delete words of list method is:

```
   public static List<string> delStr(List<string> list, string str, bool t)
    {
        if (t)
        {
            string s;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                s = list[i];
                foreach (var i1 in notWord)
                {
                    s = s.Replace(i1, "");
                }

                list[i] = s;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string s;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                s = list[i];

                s = s.Replace(str, "");


                list[i] = s;
            }
        }
        return list;

    }
```

I want to know is it correct OR, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you should post some code.

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't show any effort to solve your problem then your question is just a _gimme me teh codez_ and this is not what SO users are supposed to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("book is good ");
mylist.Add("i like flowers ");
mylist.Add("i reading book");

var mostRepeatedWord = mylist.SelectMany(x => x.Split(new [] { " " }, 
                                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                             .GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
                             .Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

- Split by space : Using `String.Split`.
- Flatten that into a single list of words: Using `SelectMany`.
- Group by each word : Using `GroupBy`.
- Order by the occurrence: Using `OrderByDescending` and `Count`.
- Get the first element: Using `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @zeynabfarzaneh do you have a `List<string>`  or what ?

Comment: list<string> mylist;

Comment: @user3185569 @zeynabfarzaneh it should be `sentences.ToArray()....` etc.

Comment: @zeynabfarzaneh I tried your code, `mostRepeatedWord` holds the value `book`.

Comment: @Berkay No need for `ToArray`

Comment: @user3185569 thanks, your code is true ,how can i find for example 5 word that most repeated ?additionally, this code extracted "the" but i don't want it ,so How can fixed it ?

Comment: Now that you have started to help a _write code for me_ user, probably you could find this [meta helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: You're right that was actually my last update for this answer. @zeynabfarzaneh If you have any additional questions please google it first maybe you can find an answer, if not please post another Question.